# Find unmatched records with 2 foreign keys

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables:

table Companies

```
+----------+-------------+----+
| Id | MainId | Type   | Name | 
+----+--------+--------+------+
| 1  |        | NO     |      |
| 2  |    1   | Filial |      |
| 3  |        | NO     |      |
| 4  |    3   | Filiar |      |
+-------------+--------+------+
```

table Employees

```
+------------------+-------+-------+
| Id | Name        | CompId| FilId |
+------------------+-------+-------+
| 333| Simon       | 1     |       |
| 444| John        | 1     | 2     |
| 555| Andrew      |       | 4     |
| 777| Dennis      | 11    |       |
| 888| John        | 3     | 10    |
+------------------+-------+-------+
```

1. How can I get all employees that work at companies listed in Companies table? 
   = At least one row (CompId or FilId) is linked to row in Companies table
2. How can I get all employees that DON'T work at companies listed in Companies table? 
   = BOTH CompId or FilId columns DON'T exist in Companies table

I have tried the solution but it doesn't perform well...

1st:

```
SELECT * FROM `Employees`  
INNER JOIN `Companies` ON `Employees`.`FilId` = `Companies`.`Id` 
OR `Employees`.`FilId` = `Companies`.`Id`
```

Added results for `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`
Removed unused columns

```
CREATE TABLE `Employees` (
 `Id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
 `CompId` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `FilId` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `empl_to_comps` (`VuzId`),
  KEY `empl_to_fils` (`FilId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `Companies` (
 `Id` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `MainId` varchar(10) DEFAULT '',
 `Type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
 PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` for both tables, so we can see the defined indexes.

Comment: Added result for you Paul

Comment: Why are you storing integers as `VARCHAR`?

Comment: I simplified my example to make it easier to understand. My Id looks like: '85FlWrSr'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.*
FROM Employees e
JOIN Companies c ON c.Id IN (e.CompId, FilId);

SELECT e.*
FROM Employees e
LEFT JOIN Companies c ON c.Id IN (e.CompId, FilId)
WHERE c.Id IS NULL;
```

#### Update

Depending on data and indexes the following two queries might be faster. And though verbose, they are more expressive than the JOIN queries.

```
SELECT e.*
FROM Employees e
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Companies c
        WHERE c.Id = e.CompId
   )
   OR EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Companies c
        WHERE c.Id = e.FilId
   );


SELECT e.*
FROM Employees e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM Companies c
      WHERE c.Id = e.CompId
  )
  AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM Companies c
      WHERE c.Id = e.FilId
  );
```

Comment: Both your requests retrieve an error:
The SELECT would examine too many records and probably take a very long time. Check your WHERE and use SET OPTION SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 if the SELECT is ok

And even if I set the option, it doesn't show anything for 15 min

Comment: @DenisEvseev Try correlated (NOT) EXISTS subqueries.  I always forget that MySQL can't optimize IN-conditions in ON clause very well.

Comment: Thanks, Paul - I have already created a C# script to check connections.

The first query retrieved all rows that means all rows connected, the second query got stuck.. You helped me to check my data!